# Would the division of classes into subclasses increase the predictive accuracy of image classification?

Tags: classification, supervised-learning

If images in a class differ in image classification, should the class be further subdivided into subclasses in which the images are more similar, or is that not necessary because different features can be learned in image classification?

For example, images should be classified into 3 classes: flowers, cars, and chairs. Is it then okay to pack all the different flowers in one flower class, or would it be better to further subdivide the class into daisies, tulips, dahlias, asters, and so on. If an aster is found, then I also know that it is a flower.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your problem.

What do you need to predict? If you need only the information whether the input is a flower, a car, or a chair, then there is no need to subdivide it.

However, it is always a good idea to do experiments and see the results.
Train different models using subdivided classes and some with the target as-is and compare the performance.

Comment: Thanks, I just need the information whether it is a flower, a car or a chair.